# How do you make a useReducer hook increase a specific object property value after pressing a button in Typescript ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js, react-tsx

I am trying to increase the value of one of Attribute's object properties (STR, AGI, INT, and CHA) whenever the "plus" button each one has is clicked. I've figured out how to make each button and property show up on my website, but I'm trying to find a more intuitive way to increase the value of each property using useReducer actions. My previous solution to this was to create a seperate useReducer action for each property that would increment the property that the action was tied to by one. This lead to A LOT of excess code and I am trying to find a better solution. I want to make a single "inc_Attributes" action that would allow each property's value to be increased individually without having a seperate action for increasing each Attribute property. How would I make a single useReducer action that could do this?

Inside index.tsx, it says that the value in "({[key]: value + 1}))" is of type unknown and shows up as an error, despite me using value in attributes.tsx almost the same way and it working perfectly fine. Another thing of note is that whenever I press one of the buttons that one of the Attribute properties are tied to, it gives me the error: "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {*/Attributes object property name here/*}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." My code is below.

index.tsx:

```
import { createContext, Dispatch, useReducer } from 'react'
import Background from '@/components/background';
import Attributes from '@/components/attributes';
import Proficiencies from '@/components/proficiencies';
import Skills from '@/components/skills';

export const context = createContext<{ contextState: any, contextDispatch: Dispatch<string> } | null>(null);

export const initialState = {
  Level: 1,
  Background: {
    Gender: "",
    Father: "",
    Early_Life: "",
    Adulthood: "",
    Adventuring_Reason: "",
  },
  Attribute_Points: 4,
  Attributes: {
    STR: 5,
    AGI: 5,
    INT: 4,
    CHA: 5
  },
  Skill_Points: 0,
  Skills: {
    Ironflesh: 1,
    Power_Strike: 1,
    Power_Throw: 1,
    Power_Draw: 1,
    Weapon_Master: 1,
    Shield: 1,
    Athletics: 1,
    Riding: 2,
    Horse_Archery: 1,
    Looting: 1,
    Trainer: 1,
    Tracking: 1,
    Tactics: 1,
    Path_Finding: 1,
    Spotting: 1,
    Inventory_Management: 1,
    Wound_Treatment: 1,
    Surgery: 1,
    First_Aid: 1,
    Engineer: 1,
    Persuasion: 1,
    Prisoner_Management: 1,
    Leadership: 2,
    Trade: 1
  },
  Proficiency_Points: 0,
  Proficiencies: {
    One_Handed_Weapons: 23,
    Two_Handed_Weapons: 15,
    Polearms: 20,
    Archery: 15,
    Crossbows: 15,
    Throwing: 19
  }
}

export default function Home() {
  const reducer = (state: any, action: string) => {
    switch(action) {
      case "inc_Attributes":
        return {
          ...state, 
          Attributes: Object.entries(state.Attributes).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value + 1}))
        }
    }
  }
  
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  return (
    <context.Provider value={{contextState: state, contextDispatch: dispatch}}>
      <Attributes />
    </context.Provider>
  )
}
```

attributes.tsx:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { context } from '../pages/index';

export default function Attributes() {
    const stateContext = useContext(context);
    return (
        <div>
            {Object.entries(stateContext?.contextState.Attributes).map(([key, value]) => (
                <ul>
                    <button onClick={() => stateContext?.contextDispatch('inc_Attributes')}>+</button> 
                    <p>{key} {value}</p>
                </ul>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried looking into the error that React gave me but none of the solutions I found helped. I also tried creating an interface with "[keys: string]: number" written inside, but I couldn't find a way to plug it in to my action that didn't give me an error message.

Comment: You are using Typescript in your project, but then ***not*** really using it? You've typed the context `contextState` value as `any`, so you've lost any typings and any type inferring capabilities right then and there. Use Typescript and declare your types so you aren't fighting your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `contextState` looks to have a fixed structure, I think it could be helpful to define types clearly for many (if not all) properties of it, which might prevent potential errors like the current one in `reducer`.

Demo of the following basic example on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-9eenbm?file=src/App.tsx)

Define type for `contextState` specifying the `Attributes` (and potentially more) property. Here `action` is structured with a string `type` to mark the action type in `reducer`, and an object `payload` to carry values, such as the target attribute(s) being increased here, but this is an optional approach.

```
interface state {
  Attributes?: {
    [key: string]: number;
  };
  [key: string]: any;
}

interface action {
  type: string;
  payload: { [key: string]: string | number };
}

export const context = createContext<{
  contextState: state;
  contextDispatch: Dispatch<action>;
}>({ contextState: {}, contextDispatch: () => {} });
```

In `reducer`, consider to use `reduce()` instead of `map()` to iterate `[key, value]` of `Attributes`, so that the result can be saved as an object to be updated in `state`.

Here I think it would be safe to add `!` to omit the `undefined` check for `Attributes` (since it is always given initial values), but if preferred otherwise, check the value for `undefined` in runtime.

```
const reducer = (state: state, action: action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case 'inc_Attributes': {
      const { Attributes } = state;
      return {
        ...state,
        Attributes: Object.entries(Attributes!).reduce(
          (acc, [key, value]) =>
            payload[key]
              ? { ...acc, [key]: value + Number(payload[key]) }
              : { ...acc, [key]: value },
          {}
        ),
      };
    }
    default: {
      return { ...state };
    }
  }
};
```

At where `contextDispatch` is used, pass the string `type` and object `payload` in the structure defined before, so that one or more attributes can be updated by this action.

While the action type remains `"inc_Attributes"`, here I think decreasing the value with minus number should also work, considering the way it has been wired up in `reducer`.

```
<ul>
  {Object.keys(Attributes!).map((key) => (
    <li key={key}>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          stateContext?.contextDispatch({
            type: "inc_Attributes",
            payload: { [key]: 1 },
          })
        }
      >
        {`${key} + 1`}
      </button>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```